# Post files with AJAX + jQuery with input element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to POST form data with AJAX + jQuery using the code below

```
<script>    
$("#submit1").click(function(){
  testSubmit(event);
});

function testSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData();
  var file_data = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files; // for multiple files
  for(var i = 0;i<file_data.length;i++){
    data.append("file_"+i, file_data[i]);
  }

  var other_data = $('#form_id').serializeArray();
  $.each(other_data,function(key,input) {
    data.append(input.name,input.value);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}  
</script>
```

Here submit1 is a button on form form_id

This code is working fine, however the below line

```
data.append("file_"+i, file_data[i]);
```

as you can see posts the file with id of file_0, file_1 and so on. How can I get this to be the actual id of the input element rather than being a generic file_0, file_1 etc ?

Thanks for reading this

Comment: Please show your HTML too.  Are you using a input type file with multiple like this?  `<input type="file" id="file1" multiple/>`

Comment: No I am not using multiple file type at this stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jQuery then why not something like this

```
$('input[type="file"]').each(function($i){
  data.append($(this).prop("id"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
});
```

Entire Code :-

```
<script>    
  $("#submit1").click(function(){
    testSubmit(event);
  });

  function testSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();

    $('input[type="file"]').each(function($i){
      data.append($(this).prop("id"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
    });

    var other_data = $('#form_id').serializeArray();
    $.each(other_data,function(key,input){
      data.append(input.name,input.value);
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: 'test.php',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  }   
</script>
```

Comment: Tried it, got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'prop'

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using ?

Comment: I just tried your standalone code (as the rest of entire was the same), it worked, I have a question though, will this work for multiple uploads ? specifically what are the two 0 indexes in : $(this)[0].files[0], also what is variable $i in the each loop. Thank you so much. I will accept your solution shortly

Comment: Glad that it worked.. The first [0] returns the file DOM element and the second [0] I think returns the file object with which you can access the file attributes.

Comment: I would say the `$i` is not required since the index is not being used, but it's not hurting anything to have it.